# How to wait for events without blocking windows messages?

Tags: c#, events, outlook, wait

This is a question about keeping a C# thread alive while waiting for events.

I am writing a C# application that shall start an instance of outlook (or re-use any existing instance if there is one active), create a mailitem and show it and then wait for the close event or send event for the mailitem.

The application will not be an add-in running inside of outlook, but will be executed from outside of outlook to create the outlook instance and the mailitem.

Since my application is not running from within the gui of outlook, but rather is starting the gui of outlook, I somehow need to keep my process alive until the events (send or close) are received. If my application returns and dies after displaying the outlook message, my eventhandlers will be dead as well.

**Question:** *How am I supposed to keep the application alive while waiting for the events?*

Since my thread is the one creating the mailitem and showing it in the outlook window, is my thread responsible for not blocking possible messages from being delivered to the outlook window?

My thought was to have a method looking like this for keeping the process alive while waiting

```
while(!MailClosed){
   lock(mailLock){
      Monitor.Wait(mailLock);
   }
}
```

and then let the event handlers for send and close call another method to wake the waiter when they are done processing the event

```
private void SignalClose(){
   lock(mailLock){
      MailClosed = true;
      Monitor.Pulse(mailLock);
   }
}
```

Would doing this block possible messages from being delivered to the outlook window holding my mailitem? Does anyone have a better solution for handling this situation?

Comment: What's you question example. Or what is the problem. Keeping an application Alive is as simple as not returning and keeping you're event handlers in scope.

Comment: If I in my Main method vall mailItem.Display() to open the mailitem in an outlook window, I need to keep the Main method from returning. To not return, I must keep the control either in a loop or som kind of sleep. My question is - how do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

**You can use an `ApplicationContext` to keep a message loop running.**

I'm not sure whether the below example is what you're looking for, but I'll give it a try.

```
static class Program
{
    private static ApplicationContext _context;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        using (_context = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            var message = new OutlookMailMessage();

            message.Closed += new EventHandler(message_Closed);

            Application.Run(_context);
        }
    }

    static void message_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Perform processing after the message has been send or closed.

        _context.ExitThread();
    }
}
```

The above code starts an `ApplicationContext` which you can use instead of showing a `Form`. This keeps a message loop running until `ExitThread` is called. With this, you can use the event handler of the message close or send event to do some processing, and then exit the application using the `ExitThread` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about blocking calls, you can start the Outlook instance in a separate thread, then your main thread can Thread.Sleep() in that while loop so that it's not checking as often.

My solution isn't elegant, but you're probably not too worried about a whole lot of deadlocking, so it should work.